# htaccess pretty urls for my site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a php website
I tried different htaccess codes but not getting what I want
I have the the following urls

```
http://mydomain/users.php?name=alex
```

want to look like

```
http://mydomain/users/alex
```

and

```
http://mydomain/items.php?name=pepsi
```

want to look like

```
http://mydomain/items/pepsi
```

or it will be very good to hide users and items too

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?name=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?name=$1
```

and more but these are not working

Comment: Well, so what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /users\.php\?name=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /users/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /users.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /items\.php\?name=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /items/%2\? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^items/(.*)$ /items.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh/try it on a different browser? The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)/(.*)  $1.php?name=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I am getting not found error, is there any changes needed at server level in some ini file, I m trying this on localhost

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess file?

Comment: CURRENT: http://mydomain/items.php?name=pepsi WANT-TO-HAVE:http://mydomain/items/pepsi    BUT THIS GIVE ERROR TRYING ALL ABOVE CODES

Comment: Ok check edited answer and make sure this is the only code in your .htaccess.